# What is the architecture of ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640?

Tags: tensorflow, cnn, computer-vision, object-detection

What is the architecture of ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640, which is a model available on TensorFlow model zoo. If my understanding is correct, mobilenet is used  for feature extraction , while SSD is used for detection. So what is the purpose of FPNlite and where is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### SSD_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640

The architecture of **ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640** is a combination of the **MobileNet v2** architecture for feature extraction and the **Single Shot Detector (SSD)** architecture for object detection, with the addition of a **Feature Pyramid Network Lite (FPN Lite)** module.

**MobileNet v2** is a lightweight convolutional neural network (CNN) architecture that is designed for efficient computation on mobile and embedded devices. It uses depthwise separable convolutions and residual connections to reduce the number of parameters and improve the performance of the network. MobileNet is used for **feature extraction**, which means it is responsible for identifying key features in the input image that can be used for object detection.

**SSD** is a popular object detection algorithm that uses a set of default bounding boxes, called anchor boxes, to predict the location and class of objects in an input image. It combines the predictions from these anchor boxes with a **non-maximum suppression (NMS)** algorithm to produce the final detection results. **SSD** is used for detection, which means it takes the extracted features and uses them to identify the location of objects in the image.

**FPN Lite** is a lightweight version of the **Feature Pyramid Network (FPN) architecture**, which is commonly used in object detection tasks ***to combine high-resolution features from shallow layers with low-resolution features from deep layers to improve detection accuracy***. In the **ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640 model**, the **FPN Lite** module is used to combine the output of the **MobileNet v2** and **SSD** layers, providing additional contextual information for the object detection task to improve the accuracy of the object detection by incorporating information from multiple scales.

Comment: Thank you. Would you also say that the architecture of ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn is similar? The difference being the use of resnet50 for feature extraction and FPN to combine the outputs of Resnet and SSD layers?

Comment: In the ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn model, the FPN is used to extract features from the input image, and the ResNet50 CNN is used as the backbone network to generate the feature pyramid. The features from the FPN are then fed into the SSD network, which performs object detection using a set of default boxes